# maven-compiler plugin groovy-eclipse: compilation failed

Tags: java, maven, groovy, junit, pom.xml

[image]

For this plugin If I don't  use configuration and dependencies my project wasn't able to detect src/main/groovy and target classes are not being generated. If use them I was able generate target classes but build was failing with error Groovy-Eclipse Compilation failed

What changes I need to make in the plugin so that build will be success and target folder will have src/main/groovy files so that I can test them by creating objects of groovy files

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Also add the errors you got while compiling (as text)

Comment: please also include the detail error message of Groovy-Eclipse Compilation failed